# How to boot a Sony Vaio E Series running Windows 8 into Safe Mode

Tags: windows-8, sony-vaio, safe-mode

Following a bad graphics driver update leaving my screen completely black at boot I had a huge amount of trouble getting into Safe Mode to roll back the driver.

First off the problem is that <kbd>F8</kbd> doesn't work any more to get into the Boot Options screen at startup. Sources on the internet suggest <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F8</kbd> but this doesn't appear to work for Sony Vaios.

If you do manage to get to the W8 Recovery screen, going to `Troubleshoot > Advanced Options` as suggested by [How to Geek](http://www.howtogeek.com/107511/) doesn't have the Windows Startup Options option.

I post my answer below to save anyone else who has this problem a few hours of headache.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Getting to the Recovery screen

Sony Vaios appear to not allow you to use <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F8</kbd> to get to Recovery Screen.

In order to do this, [turn off your laptop and press the purple <kbd>ASSIST</kbd> button](http://community.sony.com/t5/Windows-8/How-to-boot-safe-mode/td-p/103841). This will take you into the Recovery screen. Note that you do not have to press the power on button.

### Booting into safe mode

Because the Windows Startup Settings menu option is missing, you will have to do the following to get into Safe Mode:

1. From recovery, go `Troubleshoot > Advanced Options > Command Prompt`
2. Enter the following `bcdedit /set {default} safeboot network` hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>
3. Type `exit` and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> to exit Command Prompt
4. Click continue, your comptuer will now boot into safe mode

### Getting to device manager

You can't get to system settings by searching in W8 Start mode - instead you need to do

5. <kbd>Start</kbd>
6. Type `run`, hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>
7. In the Run box, type `mmc devmgmt.msc` and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>

### Getting out of Safe Mode

Follow steps 1-4 but instead of 2, run the command `bcdedit /deletevalue {default} safeboot`